# how to add autosize UITextView within UITableViewCell？

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I am using Swift2.0 with Xcode7 and my problem is like this.

I get a UITextView within UITableViewCell:
[image]

When i type into the UITextView, I want the size of UITextView and UITableViewCell will change automatically according to the length of what I typed. Also, when I enter this page, the size of UITextView and UITableViewCell are different based on the length of text read from database.

I searched a lot from Google but failed to make it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set UITextView height dynamically inside a custom UITableViewCell with autolayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369724/how-to-set-uitextview-height-dynamically-inside-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-au)

Comment: I tried the method it offered but does not work. In my opinion, the label is auto-sized based on the text it has but UITextView is based on the text it typed.